# Error when trying to use QSettings in a MFC app

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, mfc

in dlg.h, i put the following

```
   #include<QSettings>
```

it compiles with no problems
but when i try to do the operations in the .cpp

```
   void dlg::OnBnClickedOk(){

QString qstr("config/Config.ini"); //convert Cstring to QString

QSettings settings(qstr, QSettings::IniFormat); }
```

i got the following errors:

```
     error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QSettings::~QSettings(void)" (__imp_??1QSettings@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Dlg::OnBnClickedOk(void)" (?OnBnClickedOk@Dlg@@QAEXXZ)
```

and more of errors similar to this but is too long so i'm not showing it here
the reason why i didnt use Qstring direct but converting from Cstring become whenever i create a QString object i'm getting this similar errors too
anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the linker to include the appropriate Qt library either in the project settings or by adding the library to the project. You can add it to your project by right click on it in the Solution Explorer, selecting "Add" and then "Existing Item".

Comment: thanks for replying, i added a number of qt path but still can't get rid of the errors

Comment: Did you simply add the paths or did you add add the actual library to the "Additional Dependencies" section of the project settings?

Comment: hey really thanks alot for yr replies, i finally found the "additional Dependencies" section u mentioned, but i don't find any .lib files in the qt folder. and the space there needs me to manually type in the whole path right?

Comment: Mingw (Windows version of Qt compiled with Mingw by default) uses `.a` files as libs. You should find a way to convert `.a` to `.lib`, that is not trivial for `c++`, or make qt with Visual Studio

Comment: thanks chet shimpson! manage to add in the libs and no more errors but when i try to run the app i got this error "the program can't start because qtcored4.dll is missing" which i cant find it anywhere in my at folder

Comment: @wee Windows has to be able to find the DLL's that your program requires. Add the directory containing the DLL files to the end of the _PATH_ system variable. http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html